# Date paginator for Twitter Bootstrap startDate and endDate is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepaginator

In my date paginator I am able to call selected date and it is working but `startDate` and `endDate` is not working.

I am using this library http://jondmiles.com/bootstrap-datepaginator/

In this `startDate` and `endDate` is not working based on the given document. Is their any other way?

This is my working code.

```
var options = {

         format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
         startDate: '2013-01-01',
         endDate: '2013-12-31', 

        onSelectedDateChanged: function (event,date) {

        }
    }

     $('#datepaginator_sample_1').datepaginator(options);
```

Comment: Include code, what isn't working. Do you know from an error message or are you seeing unexpected results?

Comment: I am giving startDate as Today but its taking all days(default date paginator is coming as it is) without hiding past date its coming. No error message .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you too look at this project because of it's popularity: https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

use it like this when it is loaded in your project:

```
//create a new date range picker
$('#daterange').daterangepicker({ startDate: '2014-03-05', endDate: '2014-03-06' });

//change the selected date range of that picker
$('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate('2014-03-01');
$('#daterange').data('daterangepicker').setEndDate('2014-03-31');
```